# I want to sync only those data whose first names are 'Lily' from sales/service cloud to synchronized DE in marketing cloud. Is that possible?

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, marketing-cloud-connect, data-views

I want to sync only those data whose first names are 'Lily' from sales/service cloud to synchronized DE in marketing cloud. Is that possible? Basically can a filter firstName = 'Lily' be applied to sync only limited data in synchronized data extension or does it work only for boolean??

Comment: Remember to [mark the answer to your question as accepted](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) if it has been helpful

Answer (score 1):

You can only filter based on a boolean field:

> Filter the synchronized records you choose to import using the Records
> Collection buttons.
>
> -To import all records, select All records.
>
> -To import only records with an email address, select All records
> with an email address.
>
> -To import only records created after a specified date, select All
> records created since and specify the date.
>
> -To use a Boolean filter to import records, select All records with
> and enter the Boolean value. Select an attribute, set the operator,
> and choose True or False.

Doc: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_cab_creating_and_interacting_with_synchronized_data_sources.htm&language=en_US&type=5